# How can I put "charge x amount of money for x amount of square footage" in my code?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment for my programming class, creating a program for a lawn care service. For part of the assignment, I must create a method that charges $5 per 1000 square feet of land for a commercial business and $6 per 1000 square feet of land for a residential home, my question is how can I implement that into my code? This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.println("Make your choice: ");
        System.out.println("1. Commercial");
        System.out.println("2. Residential");
        System.out.println("3. Done");
        choice = in.nextInt();
        if (choice!= 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3)
            System.out.println("Incorrect entry, try again!\n");
    }while(choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3);

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            commercial();
            break;
        case 2:
            residential();
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
            break;
    }
}

private static void commercial(){
    boolean multi;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Commercial Customer");
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer phone number: ");
    String phone = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer address: ");
    String address = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the square footage of the property: ");
    String foot = scanner.nextLine();
    Double footage = Double.parseDouble(foot);
    System.out.println("Please type true if there is a multi-property discount: ");
    String discount = scanner.nextLine();
    if (discount.substring(0,1).equals("t") || discount.substring(0,1).equals("T")){
        multi = true;
    }
    else{
        multi =false;
    }
    Commercial cust = new Commercial(name, phone, address, footage, multi);
    //cust.calculateCharges();
}

private static void residential(){
    boolean senior;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Residential Customer");
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer phone number: ");
    String phone = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer address: ");
    String address = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the square footage of the property: ");
    String foot = scanner.nextLine();
    Double footage = Double.parseDouble(foot);
    System.out.println("Please type true if there is a senior discount: ");
    String discount = scanner.nextLine();
    if (discount.substring(0,1).equals("t") || discount.substring(0,1).equals("T")) {
        senior = true;
    }
    else{
        senior = false;
    }
    Residential cust = new Residential(name, phone, address, footage, senior);
    //cust.calculateCharges();

}

//public static double calculateCharges(){
    //double seniordis;
    //double multidis;
//}
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind that this is not a code-writing service. What exactly is your question, and what output do you want? Do you not just need to capture the size of the lawn and then do a calculation based on the 'choice' value? I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - why don't you add:

```
Double price = (footage * 5.0) / 1000.0;
System.out.println("The price is $" + price);
```

to the end of the commercial function and the same code to the residential function but replacing the 5.0 with a 6.0.

What you'd be doing here is multiplying the footage by the per footage cost e.g. 6/1000 and then displaying it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to implement the `calculateCharge function`, it seems like you may be a little confused on the difference between a static method and an instance method.

A static method belongs to the class and can be invoked without an instance of the class. On the other hand, an instance method belongs to an object of the class and can only be called after creating an object of that class.

For example, suppose I have a class `Car` with an instance variable `mileage` and two functions:

```
public double getMileage() {
     return mileage;
}

public static double convertMileageToKm(double mileageInMiles) {
     return mileageInMiles * 1.609;
}
```

If I want to call `getMileage`, I need to make an instance of the class `Car`.

```
Car car1 = new Car();
int milage1 = car1.getMilage();
```

However, I can call `convertMileagetoKm` without a `Car` object since it belongs to the class

```
int milageInKm = Car.convertMileageToKm(milage1);
```

In your code, you are calling a static method `calculateCharges` on objects of the classes `Residential` and `Commercial`.

There are several ways to fix this, and I think it would be a useful exercise for you to step back and consider how you want to organize your code before proceeding.